# cakephp Auth Component: login fails everytime

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have developed authentication mechanism in cakePHP prior to this successfully however this time i don't know what is wrongand every time I will be prompted wrong user name/password. I have used ***Auth*** component and here are details:

Model names: **User**,**License**

 sample user info: username: `ahmad_agha` password:`e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` which is md5 of `123456`

I don't know if it is important in this case or not, but i have **enabled** admin routing for my controllers.

**AppController.php:**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha256'
                    )
                )
            )),
        'Cookie');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        Security::setHash('md5');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'
            => 'licenses', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'
            => 'owners', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->allow('signup', 'confirm', 'login', 'logout', 'notauthorized', 'display');
        $this->Auth->authorize = array('controller');
        $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user('id'));
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.activated' => '1');
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Here is where we should verify the role and give access based on role

        return true;
    }
```

}

**Login.ctp for User's View**

```
<div class="users form">
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo md5('136112'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('لطفا نام کاربری و کلمه عبور را وارد کنید'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>'نام کاربری'));
        echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>'کلمه عبور'));
        echo $this->Form->input('remember_me',array('label'=>'مرا به خاطر بسپار','type'=>'checkbox'));
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('ورود')); ?>
</div>
```

and here is the login() action of **UsersController.php**:

```
function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            /* if (!empty($this->data)) {
              if (empty($this->data['User']['remember_me'])) {
              $this->Cookie->delete('User');
              } else {
              $cookie = array();
              $cookie['username'] = $this->data['User']
              ['username'];
              $cookie['password'] = $this->data['User']
              ['password'];
              $this->Cookie->write('User', $cookie, true, '+2 weeks');
              }
              unset($this->data['User']['remember_me']);
              } */
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your password is md5 hashed while in config for Auth you have set `'hashType' => 'sha256'`. So the mismatch of hash types is quite obvious. Setting `Security::setHash('md5')` isn't going to do anything since the hashtype set in Auth config will take priority.

You need to change the `hashType` to `md5`. Also simply saving md5 hash of password in db won't work since password hasher appends a salt (Security.salt specified in your core.php) to the password before hashing. So do `(new SimplePasswordHasher)->hash('123456')` to get the hashed value which need to be stored in db. All this is explained in the CakePHP manual btw.